# How save keras model in .pbtxt file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to save my model to .pbtxt file.

I use code from https://medium.com/@sebastingarcaacosta/how-to-export-a-tensorflow-2-x-keras-model-to-a-frozen-and-optimized-graph-39740846d9eb:

```
densenet_wrapper = DenseNet121(weights='imagenet',
                        include_top=False,
                        input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(densenet_wrapper )
    model.add(Dense(5, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=opt, 
                  metrics=['mse', 'acc'])
    print(model.summary())
    return model

model = build_model()
```

**#Full code to freeze your Keras model and save it**

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2
import numpy as np 


frozen_out_path = '1.pb' # name of the .pb file
frozen_graph_filename = 'frozen_graph'

# Convert Keras model to ConcreteFunction
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))

# Get frozen ConcreteFunction
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()
layers = [op.name for op in frozen_func.graph.get_operations()]

                 
# Save its text representation
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir=frozen_out_path,                  
                  name=f"{frozen_graph_filename}.pbtxt",
                  as_text=True)
```

I use
"from keras.applications import DenseNet121"

Very important to keep this and not use tf.keras.

This code work in TF 2.4 + Keras 2.4.3

But dont work in TF 2.2 + Keras 2.3

**Error:**

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py in _import_graph_def_internal(graph_def, input_map, return_elements, validate_colocation_constraints, name, producer_op_list)
    496         results = c_api.TF_GraphImportGraphDefWithResults(
--> 497             graph._c_graph, serialized, options)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    498         results = c_api_util.ScopedTFImportGraphDefResults(results)

InvalidArgumentError: Input 0 of node sequential_1/densenet121/conv1/bn/AssignSubVariableOp was passed float from sequential_1/densenet121/conv1/bn/27918:0 incompatible with expected resource.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

11 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py in _import_graph_def_internal(graph_def, input_map, return_elements, validate_colocation_constraints, name, producer_op_list)
    499       except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
    500         # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
--> 501         raise ValueError(str(e))
    502 
    503     # Create _DefinedFunctions for any imported functions.

ValueError: Input 0 of node sequential_1/densenet121/conv1/bn/AssignSubVariableOp was passed float from sequential_1/densenet121/conv1/bn/27918:0 incompatible with expected resource.
```

Please help me save model to pbtxt

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/omimo/5d393ed5b64d2ca0c591e4da04af6009) it may help to solve your issue. Thanks!